# Можно ли говорить «сильно красивый», «сильно умный»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия, разговорная-речь

То есть использовать "сильно" в значении "очень".

Comment: Если вы получили полезный ответ, отметьте его галочкой, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Это распространенное явление в **просторечии** (такая оценка дана, например, в работе Г. И. Кустовой «Количественные значения качественных слов»):

> ― **Сильно умные** девчонки вечно грузят мозги себе и другим. [Дмитрий
>   Емец. Таня Гроттер и колодец Посейдона (2004)] (Пример из [НКРЯ](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=10&spp=50&spd=10&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2).)

*Сильно* в значении 'очень', характеризующем прилагательные, в строгой литературной речи употреблять **однозначно не стоит**.

При этом с причастиями и глаголами — вполне можно: *Сильно потёртые джинсы*.

Из упомянутой выше статьи:

> Исходное сильно относится к воздействию, но не к результату, т.е.
>   является именно мерой усилий: можно сказать *сильно сдавил тюбик*, но не
>   **сильно выдавил пасту* (там, где сила уже не действует, «качественное» сильно неприменимо). В производном (степенном) значении сильно
>   характеризует состояние. Но это такое состояние, которое является
>   результатом предшествующего изменения, предшествующего процесса,
>   предшествующего воздействия. Поэтому сильно нормально сочетается с
>   глаголами, обозначающими изменение п р и з н а к а или состояния:
>   сильно
>   *состарился/разрушился/нагрелся/раскалился/остыл/запылился/испачкался/износился/потрепался/порвался/поседел/выцвел/полинял/облез/
>   обветшал/пожелтел/заржавел/промок/вымок/зарос.*
>
> Сильно сочетается также с причастиями, поскольку состояние,
>   обозначенное причастием, сохраняет связь с глаголом и мыслится как
>   результат изменения, но плохо сочетается с прилагательными, так как
>   они не содержат указания на связь с процессом, изменением:
>
> *сильно испачканный — *сильно грязный* ( —> очень)
>
> *сильно запыленный — *сильно пыльный*
>
> *сильно пожелтевший — *сильно желтый*
>
> Впрочем, в просторечии такие сочетания возможны: *сильно умный, сильно
>   грамотный, сильно шустрый, сильно много*.

Comment: А **почему** _однозначно не стоит_?  Ведь словари не дают никаких пометок. В МАС: 2. Очень, весьма, крайне. У Ефремовой: 2) Очень. У Кузнецова: 2. Очень. http://endic.ru/academic/Silno-57745.html

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова вы не учитываете особенности сочетаемости слова _сильно_. Я уточню ответ, спасибо за наводку.

Comment: И Вам спасибо, _Aer,_ — за разъяснение. Есть, правда, случаи, которые не подходят под просторечие. _Зарева слева, по северной стороне, ещё добавились. Близких – уже три, а какое-то большое – сильно подальше_ (А. Солженицын).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова _подальше_ — наречие, оно здесь вообще не обсуждается.

Comment: Да, не обсуждается. Но что же мешает пообсуждать (сильно красиво, сильно грамотно). В примерах есть "сильно много" — его мы относим к просторечию. А "сильно подальше" у Солженицына мне таким не показалось. Вот и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Только иронически.

Типо шибко грамотный. Больно умный.

**[СИЛЬНО:](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]